# element .innerText not displaying

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace the text content of two divs ("city" and "budget"), one with a random US city from an array and one with a randomly generated number. The code works fine when I run it in the console, but for some reason it won't display in the browser. Any idea what's going wrong here? For my purposes I'm not using JQuery, just straight JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<div id="result">
    <div class="city">
        <h1>City</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="budget">
        <h1>Budget</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function city() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('.city').innerText = usCities[Math.floor(Math.random() * usCities.length)];
}

function budget() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('.budget').innerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) + 100000;
}
```

Comment: Remove the dot from `getElementsByClassName` --> `getElementsByClassName('city')`.

Comment: You have `getElements...` plural, meaning an array of elements. Your requested element should be in index 0. getElementsByClassName('city")[0]

Comment: Tried both solutions and neither seem to be working... the thing is, when I run both functions in the console they work, they results just don't display in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are:

1. You doesn't give [0] to `getElementsByClassName`.
2. Using `.` in the paremeter of `getElementsByClassName`.
3. You doesn't call the function
4. You doesn't define the `usCities`

This should works:

```js
let usCities = ["Chicago", "New York"]

function city() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('city')[0].innerText = usCities[Math.floor(Math.random() * usCities.length)];
}

function budget() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('budget')[0].innerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) + 100000;
}
city();
budget();
```

```html
<div id="result">
  <div class="city">
    <h1>City</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="budget">
    <h1>Budget</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't call the function! That fixed it. Thank you!